# String interpolation in Angular

Tags: angular

My **app.component.ts** code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isDisabled = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

My **app.component.html** code:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ isDisabled }}" disabled="{{ isDisabled }}" />
```

- The string interpolation for the `disabled` attribute is evaluated to a truthy value (thus, making the input disabled from the get-go)
- The string interpolation for the `value` attribute is evaluated to `false` initially and just after the callback of the `setTimeout` is executed, the `value` attribute of the input is `true`. (this is the behavior I expected for the `disabled` attribute also)

Q: What's causing the difference in the way these two string interpolations work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disabled` will disable an element whether it is true or false, it's presence means that the element will be disabled. 
Angular will not add the disabled element at all for `[disabled]="variable"` if variable is false.